# Real Analysis - Differentiable Functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Prove the following: If $f'$ exists and is bounded on $(a,b]$, then the right hand limit of $f$ exists.

I get the feeling that this should be simple, but I'm having a hard time with it.

Comment: Where is your function $f$ defined?

Comment: So far I have been trying to show that if f' is bounded then f is monotone because from there it would be fairly simple, but have had no luck. The question does not say where f is defined.

Comment: Might want to put in "at $a$" at the end of your first sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Assume that $|f'(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in (a,b]$ and let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence in $(a,b]$ which converges to $a$. Then $(x_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence and, by the Mean Value Theorem,
$$|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|\leq M|x_n-x_m|$$
which implies that also $(f(x_n))_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

P.S. The boundedness of $f'$ implies that it is [Lipschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) and therefore [uniformly continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity) in $(a,b]$. Now recall the [relation between uniform continuity and the extension problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Relations_with_the_extension_problem).

Comment: @analysisishard Glad to be useful. BTW, if you are new here take a few minutes for a tour: math.stackexchange.com/tour